# How to navigate to an ASP.NET Core MVC controller in Blazor app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, controller, blazor

I have `DownloadController.cs` to `Controllers/DownloadController` with the following method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadFile(string key) 
{
    return File(...);
}
```

Also, in my `Startup.cs` I have configured the following endpoints:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default".
        pattern: "{controller}/{action}");
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});
```

So how in a Blazor view can I navigate to the controller action? I was looking for something similar to this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(...);
```

Comment: I said navigate to a controller action, not a page.

Comment: did you solve your "problem" ? Is there something similiar?

Comment: Line 4 in the `Startup.cs` should have a `,` rather than `.`. It should be `name: "default",`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do:

```
@page "/MvcLinkExample"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<button @onclick="NavigateToMvcPage">MVC Link</button>

@code {
    private void NavigateToMvcPage()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("controllername/actionname/10", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had exactly that, however, I get a 404. Is the controller stuctured any differently to normal? And do you know if my endpoint configuration is correct?

Comment: The second parameter of the NavigateTo method (true) helped in my case. I think this answer is correct.

Comment: This is an interesting problem, any changes to controller names will cause these string fields to be out of sync and break communications. Implementing a generic MVC Navigation Manager in the framework might be a good idea if cross communication between Blazor and MVC is heavily utilised.

Comment: You could always use reflection to get the name

Answer (score 0):

MVC uses "routes" to configure endpoints (Controller / Action / Area) mappings.

In the example you provided, the route would resolve to http(s)://[hostname or ip]/Download/DownloadFile/.

With the "default route", the 'key' query string param can be provided via ?key=[value-xxx] as a basic implementation.

Comment: I have tried exactly that, however I just get a 404.